# Patches in scalatest

Tags: scala, scalatest, monkeypatching

I'm new to scala and same for scalatest.

My aim is to write a Unit test for the following small piece of code:

```
import java.sql.SQLException

import com.typesafe.scalalogging.LazyLogging
import slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api._

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, ExecutionContextExecutor, Future}

object DbCreator extends LazyLogging {
  implicit val ex: ExecutionContextExecutor = ExecutionContext.global

  def createDatabaseIfNotExist(): Future[String] = {
    Database
      .forURL(url = "some host", user = "user", password = "pass", driver = "driver")
      .run(sqlu"CREATE DATABASE ...").map(_ => "created")
      .recover {
        case e: Throwable => {
          logger.error("Error!", e)
          throw new SQLException(e.getMessage)
        }
      }
  }
}
```

I've previously used python, which has the [patch concept](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch).

So my idea was to patch the `Database` class being imported and used in `createDatabaseIfNotExist`, so I can verify the different scenarios.

Unfortunately, I could not find equivalent/similar concept in scalatest.

Did I miss it?

Is my approach wrong? If so, how would u suggest me write a UT for the `createDatabaseIfNotExist` method?

Is the current `DbCreator` implementation not testable enough?

Many thanks for all help!

Answer (score 1):

I see several options:

- [scalamock](https://scalamock.org/) or some java mocking library
- [acolyte](https://github.com/cchantep/acolyte) JDBC driver (has scala DSL)
- [embedded mysql](https://github.com/wix/wix-embedded-mysql)